# CoreData child context doesn't push change to parent after save second times

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I should save Recipe if user press on the like button if dislike should remove.

I have two contexts:

Context A (parent) - persistentContainer.viewContext

Context B (childe) -

```
let childManagedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .mainQueueConcurrencyType)
childManagedObjectContext.parent = persistentContainer.viewContext
```

On the RecipeVC I have childManagedObjectContext with recipe. I use it like sandbox user can like/dislike many times.

First time:
When user Like recipe.
I save B than A contexts.
When user dislike I fetch recipe by id from the A and call delete.

But if user likes recipe again and save B changes don't appear in the A context. At this moment `hasChanges` property has sate false.

Chain: save B -> save A -> delete A -> save B -> (?) recipe should appear in the A...

Why doesn't recipe appear in the A after save?

```
func changeFavoriteStatus() {
        isFavorite = !isFavorite
        let parantContext = managedObjectContext!.parent!
        if !isFavorite {
            deleteRecipeInTheParentContext()
        } else {
            if managedObjectContext!.hasChanges {
                managedObjectContext?.performAndWait{
                    do {
                        try managedObjectContext?.save()
                    } catch {  print(error) }

                    if parantContext.hasChanges {
                        parantContext.performAndWait{
                            do {
                                try parantContext.save()
                                let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: entity.name!)
                                let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "id == %i",id)
                                fetchRequest.predicate = predicate

                                do {
                                    let recipes = try parantContext.fetch(fetchRequest) as! [Recipe]
                                    print("\(recipes.count) found")
                                } catch { print(error) }
                            } catch {
                                print(error) } } } } } }
    }

    private func deleteRecipeInTheParentContext() {
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: entity.name!)
        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "id == %i",id)
        fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
        let parantContext = managedObjectContext!.parent!

        do {
            let recipes = try parantContext.fetch(fetchRequest) as! [Recipe]

            parantContext.performAndWait {
                for reipe in recipes { parantContext.delete(reipe) }
                do {
                    try parantContext.save()
                } catch { print(error)  }
            }
        } catch { print(error)  }
    }
```

Comment: It might be that you are having a conflict. Do you try to log any of them? I am not sure (from what you wrote) but what it looks like is that you are deleting an item from context A and modifying it from context B. And if item has already been deleted on A you need to create a new one instead of modify the existing one. Most likely the second operation has no effect because the managed object is kind of a zombie; its source object in database has been removed.

Comment: @MaticOblak nothing in logs. I can print and view all params and relations of the recipe after delete.

Comment: View them where? Your context holds in-memory data retrieved from database and is then inserted back. Multiple contexts means you have multiple instances of in-memory data objects. The idea is to only keep in memory what you currently need, you modify this data and insert it back into the database on hard drive. So when one context saves into database it should not effect the second context. The second context needs to reload the data from the database to see the changes in most of the cases. So yes, you still see all the data in managed objects.